# how to write expression in WSO2 for filter mediator for 200 and other than 200 response codes

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-data-services-server

If the xml request is success "then" 200 if any other response code is generated once request is send it should be "else"

Should I define property group for this, if so how to write the expressions for 200 and non-200 codes

Answer (score 0):

Check the following code snippet.

```xml
<filter regex="200" source="$axis2:HTTP_SC">
    <then>
        // 200
    </then>
    <else>
        // Not 200
    </else>
</filter>
```